# How do I make this native query ignore blank values for a filter?

Tags: java, sql

I have a native query with a couple of filters.

When 2020 is the value it shows "2020",

When 2021 is the value it shows "2021",

When the value is NOT 2020, 2021, or ' '  (blank value) it shows "notCurrent",

When the value is blank, it shows "unknown".

The problem with this query is that there are blank/null/'' values that are displayed in the notCurrent filter.

How do I make sure these blanks/nulls ONLY show up in the "unknown" filter and NOT in the notCurrent filter. What is wrong with this query ?

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT " +
            "COUNT(DISTINCT pd.id) FILTER (WHERE c.year = '2020') AS \"2020\",  " +
            "COUNT(DISTINCT pd.id) FILTER (WHERE c.year = '2021') AS \"2021\",  " +
            "COUNT(DISTINCT pd.id) FILTER (WHERE c.year NOT IN ('2020', '2021', '')) AS \"notCurrent\",  " +
            "COUNT(pd.id) FILTER (WHERE c.year = '') AS \"unknown\" " +
```

Comment: well null and blank strings are not in `('2020', '2021', '')`, so they will be included. You could add an `and` with null checks and `trim` the year

Comment: but isn't ' ' a blank value? Why is this still showing up?

Comment: Don't store numbers as `VARCHAR`. You are asking for trouble.